# Java RecursiveLinkedList contains method

Tags: java, recursion, contains, singly-linked-list

I am working on a simple linkedList class, one of the requirement for this class is to use recurs to implement the contains method, add method and remove method.

Based on example I found I have implemented the remove method, but the contains keeps throw error for me.

Can anyone help to point out what is wrong with my contains method, thanks & regards.

```
public class RecursiveLinkedList {

private int value;
private RecursiveLinkedList next;

/*
 * Default Constructor
 * 
 * @param value an absolute int value for the current Node
 * @param next an absolute RecursiveLinkedList value for the current Node
 */
public RecursiveLinkedList(int value, RecursiveLinkedList next) {
    this.value = value;
    this.next = next;
}

/*
 * Constructor Empty, when user supplies an empty for the construcot use 
 * value = - 1 and next = null as input parameters
 * 
 * @param value an absolute int value for the current Node
 * @param next an absolute RecursiveLinkedList value for the current Node
 */
public static final RecursiveLinkedList EMPTY = new RecursiveLinkedList(-1, null) 
{
    public RecursiveLinkedList remove(int n) { return this; };

    public String toString() { return ""; };
};

public RecursiveLinkedList remove(int n) {
    if (value == n){
        return next;
    }
    //Call the remove method of the next Node if the selected Node is not the current node
    return new RecursiveLinkedList(value, next.remove(n));
}

public boolean contains(int n) {
    if (value == n){
        return true;
    }else if(next == null){
        return false;
    }
    return new RecursiveLinkedList(value, next).contains(n);
} 

public String toString() {
    return value + "," + next.toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    RecursiveLinkedList l = new RecursiveLinkedList(1,
                    new RecursiveLinkedList(2, 
                    new RecursiveLinkedList(2,
                    new RecursiveLinkedList(3, 
                    new RecursiveLinkedList(4, EMPTY)))));
    System.out.println(" Test to String Method : " + l.toString());
    System.out.println(" Test remove method " + l.remove(1).toString());
    System.out.println(" Test contains method " + String.valueOf(l.contains(4)));
}
```

}

Comment: Re: "the contains keeps throw error for me": Have you looked at the error? What did you learn from it? (What type of error is it? What is the message? What line does it occur on?)

Comment: why are you creating a new linkedlist on every return?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, it throws error at line 45 where I made mistake by creating a new Instance instead of calling next object directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent the `StackOverflowError` you should use instead:

```
public boolean contains(int n) {
    if (value == n){
        return true;
    }else if(next == null){
        return false;
    }
    return next.contains(n);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing it out, yes, I should have not create a new instance. Thanks & Regards